# Evaluate $a+2b+3c$

Tags: limits, functions

If $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac { \int _{ 0 }^{ h }{ f(x)dx-h(af(0)+bf(h/3)+cf(h)) }  }{ { h }^{ 4 } } $$ is a finite non-zero number,how to evaluate $a+2b+3c$?

Ok only hints at first.I want to solve this myself.But can't understand how to start.Any suggestion appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Makes me think of having a Taylor series for $f$ and integrating it within radius of convergence. What can be said about the coefficients? You may have to use Mean Value Theorem as well for that coefficient, not sure yet

Comment: Propably L'Hopital you know it's finit differentiate

Comment: @mjb4 Loved that one.Just solved the sum.Differentiated three times using L'Hospital and then used the fact that the numerator must be 0.Woo-hoo its done!!Thanks all of you :-)

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS:**

If $f$ is sufficiently smooth, then we can write

$$f(\alpha h)=f(0)+f'(0)\alpha h+\frac1{2!} f''(0)(\alpha h)^2+\frac1{3!} f'''(0)(\alpha h)^3+\frac{1}{4!}f''''(0)(\alpha h)^4+O(h^5)$$

and

$$\int_o^hf(x)\,dx=f(0)h+\frac1{2!}f'(0)h^2+\frac1{3!}f''(0)h^3+\frac{1}{4!}f'''(0)h^4+(h^5)$$

Comment: @sanchayandutta Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  As you know, I always try and want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

Set $f(x) = 1, x, x^2, x^3$.
You will get a series of equations
for $a, b, c$.

Solve them and here is what you get.

$\frac { \int _{ 0 }^{ h } f(x)dx-h(af(0)+bf(h/3)+cf(h))   }{ { h }^{ 4 } }
$

For $f(x) = 1$:

$ \int _{ 0 }^{ h } dx-h(a+b+c) 
=h-h(a+b+c) 
$,
so
$a+b+c = 1$.

For $f(x) = x$:

$ \int _{ 0 }^{ h } xdx-h(a\cdot 0+b(h/3)+ch) 
=h^2/2-h^2(b/3+c) 
$,
so
$b/3+c = 1/2$
or
$b+3c = 3/2$.

For $f(x) = x^2$:

$ \int _{ 0 }^{ h } x^2dx-h(a\cdot 0+b(h/3)^2+ch^2)
=h^3/3-h^3(b/9+c) 
$,
so
$b/9+c = 1/3$
or
$b+9c = 3$.

We get
$a+b+c = 1$,
$b+3c = 3/2$,
$b+9c = 3$.

Subtracting the 2nd and 3rd,
$9c = 3/2$
or
$c = 1/6$.

From the last,
$b = 3-9/6 = 3/2$.

From the first,
$a = 1-3/2-1/6
=-2/3
$.

So
$a+2b+3c
=-2/3+3+1/2
=17/6
$.

Note that,
for $f(x) = x^3$:

$ \int _{ 0 }^{ h } x^3dx-h(a\cdot 0+b(h/3)^3+ch^3) 
=h^4/4-h^4(b/27+c) 
=h^4(1/4-3/(2\cdot 27)+1/6) 
=(h^4/(4\cdot 27)(27-4-18) 
=5h^4/(4\cdot 27) 
$,